# CSS: Is there a way to define total document height?

Tags: css, height, document

I was wondering if there's any way to get the document height (not the browser's) with CSS so you can use it to define the height of a div element.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you can get the actual height, but you could use media queries to say "If the document is at least X tall, my div should be Y big". Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @SheepSlapper but "The height media feature describes the height of the output device's rendering surface (such as the height of the viewport or of the page box on a printer)." Basically browser height

Comment: @Huangism - Ahh, you're right. That's viewport height and not document height, so media doesn't make much sense. I blame lack of coffee on that one. So, I'm not sure there's a straight CSS way to do this then. Might have to fall back to Javascript/jQuery...

Comment: I only know to get body height with jquery, I don't think it is doable with css

Comment: Thanks all, guys. That's what I suspected, but wanted to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this using jQuery, as there are only certain situations where you can use height [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceonline/u6gwt/)

Code from the fiddle:

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    $('#wrapper').height(docHeight);
});
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#inner {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: probably don't even need wrapper, you can grab height of body tag

Comment: Thanks for the coding, I'm trying it now.

Comment: Hm, shoudn't the green div be as long as the red one in this example?
http://jsbin.com/ahogec/1/edit

Comment: Looks like `$(document).height()` is returning the height of the viewport. I'll have a fiddle :)